# Get Featured image from Posted Content

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I have a blog system where user inputs the image url in the post content like ->

```
hey how are you <img src="www.example.com/image.png" style="height=100px;">
```

Then I want to find this [img src] line and use it as featured image like this-> www.example.com/image.png

here is what I have tried: 
$content is the content Posted from the Form

```
preg_match('/(<img .*?>)/', $content, $img_tag);
$feature = $img_tag[0];   // This preg_match finds img src tag and provide me
$regex = '~<img.*?src=[\'"](?:view-source:)?([^"\']+).*?\/?>~';

$featured = preg_replace($regex, "$1", $feature);
```

can anyone tweak out problem Here?

Comment: So you just want to get the `src` attribute from the first `<img>` tag in the post ? Or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to extract the `src` attribute of the first `<img>` tag in the content, all you need is this:

```
preg_match_all('/<img.*src="(.*)"/', $content, $matches);

$featured = isset($matches[1][0]) ? $matches[1][0] : null;
```

Now let me explain what is happening here:

`preg_match_all` matches against the whole string, while `preg_match` stops at the first line, unless you add the `s` modifier.

As for the `$matches` array, the first index stands for the matching group. The number of the matching group is the count of `(` from the beginning of the expression until the group. `0` matches the whole expression. So `$matches[1]` stands for the results of the matching group inside `src` argument.

From that array, we take the first element, meaning the `src` attribute of the first matching `img` tag in the content.

Of course, there don't have to be any images in the content, that's why you should call `isset` before trying to access the result.

I hope this explains it.